# Example of Bott Periodicity

Tags: group-theory, functional-analysis

I am reading K-Theory for C*-algebras. I am struggling to understand why

$K_{0}(C(\mathbb{T}^{n}))$ $\cong$ $K_{1}(C(\mathbb{T}^{n}))$ $\cong$
 $\mathbb{Z}^{{2}^{n-1}}$.

However, I know that by the split exact sequence

$$ 0 \rightarrow SA \rightarrow \mathbb{T}A \rightarrow A \rightarrow 0$$
We have 
$K_{0}(\mathbb{T}A)$ $\cong$ $K_{1}(\mathbb{T}A)$ $\cong$ $ K_{0}(A)\oplus K_{1}(A) $
where $\mathbb{T}$  is the set of $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|z|=1$.